# How to get index of specific group of character in python using regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x, search, indexing

Iam trying to get all the indexes of specific group of special character ,but my regex is returning the index of single character of that group,

here is my code:-

```
a=re.finditer(r"[/ \\][\\ /]","/ \\ / \\ / \\ / /")
print([m.start(0) for m in a])
```

> its returning [0,2,4,6,8,10,12]
>
> but i want [0,2,4,6,8,10] , i only want index of "/ \" and "\ /"

Comment: @theausome yes output should be that, i've edited my post

Comment: Then try [`re.finditer(r"(/) (\\)|(\\) (/)", "/ \\ / \\ / \\")`](https://ideone.com/juvKLb) and grab the appropriate group `start()` values.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks man that worked

Comment: why my question is down voted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the character class brackets and wrap each symbol with a capturing group. Then, you may use some logic to grab the indices of the groups that matched.

```
import re
res = []
for m in re.finditer(r"(/) (\\)|(\\) (/)", "/ \\ / \\ / \\"):
    if m.group(1):
        res.extend([m.start(1), m.start(2)])
    else:
        res.extend([m.start(3), m.start(4)])

print(res) # => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/juvKLb).

Here, if Group 1 matched, that means we need to grab the start indices of Group 1 and 2, else, the start indices of Group 3 and 4.

Comment: nah it ain't returning the correct output, can u check it with string "/ \\ / \\ / \\ / /" ,its printing [0,4,8]

Comment: @AbhishekKumar It prints [`[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`](https://ideone.com/nADtO3)

Answer (score 0):

I found an better answer for that, its short one liner

```
print([m.start(0) for m in re.finditer(r"(?=(/ \\|\\ /))", "/ \\ / \\ / \\ / /")])
```